# How to delete[] memory after return has been called

Tags: c++, class, free, delete-operator

I have a class that represents a matrix and several operations on matrices. I am trying to overload the `*` operator to multiply two matrices.

```
matrix matrix::operator* (matrix param) {
  if(n!=param.n){
    matrix blah;
    return blah;}

  matrix temp(n,0);
  temp.user_matrix=mult(param.user_matrix);
  return temp;}
```

The matrices are both square so the first part is just to check that they are of the same size.This works but how should I delete the temp matrix after it has been returned to another matrix object?

Comment: You never allocate anything using `new` or `new []` so why you want to call `delete []`? You don't need to.

Comment: If you are actually allocating dynamic memory for the matrices, you should be doing that in their constructor and deallocating the memory in their destructor.

Comment: Your code will work as it is assuming you have defined the destructor and copy constructor correctly. There is no need to delete[] memory if you have done this.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't. It is automatically destroyed.

You should only `delete` objects that you've allocated with `new`.

Generally using raw `new` and `delete` is frowned upon in modern C++. Take a look at `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` for alternatives. (They are not needed in your example)

Answer (score 0):

"temp" is a local variable, scoped to your function, there is no need to free it's memory. The memory it uses is on the stack, so it's "freed" automatically by the functions suffix (the underlying code that makes up the return statement).

```
void foo() {
    int temp = 5;
    return temp + temp;
}
;; x86 ASSEMBLY (NASM/FASM syntax)
foo:
    SUB esp, 4 ;; <-- local memory for temp variable
    MOV [esp], 5 ;; temp = 5
    MOV eax, [esp] ;; eax = 5 (eax is the return-value register)
    ADD eax, eax ;; 5 + 5
    ADD esp, 4 ;; <-- "free" local memory for temp variable
    RETN
```